# How to get URL from Chrome in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, google-chrome

I tried:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName UIAutomationClient

$chromes = Get-Process -Name chrome

foreach ($chrome in $chromes) {
    if ($chrome.MainWindowHandle -eq [System.IntPtr]::Zero) {
        continue
    } else {
        $chrome.MainWindowHandle
    }

    $element = [System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement]::FromHandle($chrome.MainWindowHandle)
    $condition = [System.Windows.Automation.PropertyCondition]::New([System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement]::ClassNameProperty, "Chrome_OmniboxView")

    $edit = $element.FindFirst([System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope]::Subtree, $condition)

    $edit
}
```

`$edit` is `$null`.

Chrome version ７５ in Japan.

Comment: I *think* Selenium worked with Chrome, at least in the past. It may be worth looking at [their libraries](https://seleniumhq.github.io/docs/wd.html?#get_current_url) for this.

Comment: Thx :) but in the offline env. So I should do this using only windows default library:(

Comment: It fix! in Japan Forums has anser :)  if someone have another idea , i want to know it .    https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/5bbef0be-3046-4b6c-943f-5b6ec4fb3aa3/powershellnet1239512390chrome12398url1243421462244711237712427260412?forum=powershellja

Comment: I would post your solution as an answer. It may be useful for someone else.))